# how to add a repository as a dependency in the package.xml and add it as a component to in the cmakelists

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

There is a repository API for Kuka youbot named youbot_driver which includes other packages/folder and libraries and a Yaml file. I want to link against this repository from a catkin package(IT DOSE NOT consist of Include folder as a catkin package). There is a folder named youbot which includes .ccp and .h files. Regardless of declaring these headers in the main node, I have to add this repository to .xml and cmakelists. Would you please tell how I can do this?

sincerely,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198858/how-to-add-a-repository-as-a-dependency-in-the-package.xml-and-add-it-as-a-component-to-in-the-cmakelists./) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your package.xml add

```
<build_depend>youbot_driver</build_depend>
<run_depend>youbot_driver</run_depend>
```

and in your CMakeLists.txt add `youbot_driver` to `find_package` and `catkin_package`.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-04**:
Thanks. It means that there is no difference between a repository including some packages/folders and a single package in the way that we declare them in .xml and  cmakelists?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-05**:
Well, youbot_driver is a single package. How complexd the package is plays no role.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-26**:
@BennyRe. My problem is solved. The package could drive the youbot well. Thanks for your help.